# Angular ViewportScroller not working in angular version 14

Tags: javascript, angular, angular14

Component.ts

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

      constructor(
        private scroller: ViewportScroller,
      ) {}


      test() {
        this.scroller.scrollToAnchor('123456789');
      }
}
```

HTML

```
  <button (click)="test()">Test</button>      
  .......
  <div id="123456789">
    Test
  </div>
  .......
```

As you can see I have added viewportScoller in the component and used on the button to click but it's not working

ANGULAR VERSION: 14

Comment: Do you have id with above string in your page?

Comment: Yes I have assigned the id to the element

Comment: Please add your code as code, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

you can use scrollToElement function instead of "this.scroller.scrollToAnchor", it works for me :

```
  scrollToVersions() {
    scrollToElement('comparateur-de-version') 
  }
```

"comparateur-de-version" is the id of div in html.